# Carousel does not work on staging site, but when the site is also run on Local suddenly it does

Tags: jquery, wordpress, carousel

So I have a really bizarre problem I can't explain.

This is a staging site I have here: https://staging.marcolapegna.com/

The carousel at the start does not seem to work. However, when I turn the site on Local and visit the same link at https://staging.marcolapegna.com/ it all of a sudden does seem to work. I re-upload the files from Local to the host and the problem does not go away.

What is happening why does my staging only work once I turn on the site in Local?

If need be I uploaded all the files here: https://github.com/xVicissitudex/ASD-Sparta

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    counter = 0;
    slide = $(".cover-slider img");
    images = ["http://asd-sparta.local/wp-content/themes/ASD-Sparta/img/front-slider/gym-img.jpg",
              "http://asd-sparta.local/wp-content/themes/ASD-Sparta/img/front-slider/dumbells.jpg",
              "http://asd-sparta.local/wp-content/themes/ASD-Sparta/img/front-slider/martial-arts.jpg"
              ];
    indicators = $(".carousel-indicators > i");
    
    $(".carousel-next-icons > i:last").click(function () {
        counter++;
        if (counter == 3) counter = 0;
        slide.attr("src", images[counter]);
        indicators.css("opacity",".3");
        indicators.eq(counter).css("opacity", "1");
        clearInterval(slideshow);
        slideshow = setInterval(fadeSlide, 6000);
    });
    
    $(".carousel-next-icons > i:first").click(function () {
        counter--;
        if (counter == -1) counter = 2;
        slide.attr("src", images[counter]);
        indicators.css("opacity",".3");
        indicators.eq(counter).css("opacity", "1");
        clearInterval(slideshow);
        slideshow = setInterval(fadeSlide, 6000);
    });

    indicators.click(function () {
        indicator = $(this).index();
        slide.attr("src", images[indicator]);
        indicators.css("opacity",".3");
        indicators.eq(indicator).css("opacity", "1");
        counter = indicator;
        clearInterval(slideshow);
        slideshow = setInterval(fadeSlide, 6000);
    });

    function fadeSlide (){
        counter++;
        if (counter == 3) counter = 0;
        indicators.css("opacity",".3");
        indicators.eq(counter).css("opacity", "1");
        slide.fadeOut().attr("src", images[counter]).fadeIn(1000)
    }

    let slideshow = setInterval(fadeSlide, 6000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cover-slider">
    <img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/img/front-slider/gym-img.jpg')?>">
    <div class="carousel-next-icons">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left fa-xl"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right fa-xl"></i>
    </div> 
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-circle fa-2xs"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-circle fa-2xs"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-circle fa-2xs"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i mean, first of all, the URL for the images is obviously not the same on the staging site. I get a lot of 404s for the images in the console.

Comment: You could use splide slider as a gutenberg block with this plugin:
https://github.com/frizzant/cs-splide-slider
And adjust whatever you need to. I created that quite some time ago. It's not pre-built, you'll have to compile the project with node once, before you upload it.
Hardcoding images like you did, is bound to give you issues.

Comment: Yes they are matching, but they are incorrect. I see:  https://asd-sparta.local/wp-content/themes/ASD-Sparta/img/front-slider/martial-arts.jpg which resolves to your localhost. This means, you will actually not get a 404, since it will look up the images in your local instance. Turn off your local host, and you will get 404s too.